# mysql auto backup on windows

Tags: backup, mysql, database-backups

Is there any software or tools that can regular auto backup mysql database every few hours?

It should backup on local hardisk and also to a different server via FTP?

Im using mySQL (Wamp) on Windows.

What about backup websites regular?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use windows own scheduler and have that fire mysqldump. You could see [this blogpost](http://realm3.com/articles/how_to_schedule_regular_mysql_backups_in_windows) for inspiration.

Comment: Just now noticed that you wanted it uploaded via ftp to another site. That should be real easy as well. Just have the scheduler process all files in your directory of completed backups.

Comment: This is why we ask people to not post only links, but to sumarize the link contents in the answer.

Comment: Is there any blaog to similar theme?